# Isometric rendering for 3d tiles (and 2d sprites)

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am very new to libgdx and graphics in general so forgive me if I am not quite understanding correctly.

I followed the tutorial on the badlogicgames block regarding [Isometric Tilemap Rendering](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2032). I have successfully implemented everything discussed in the post, however I have a few issues I am trying to work out and questions I need to ask.

1. I would like to render tiles with two dimensions (possibly a 3d model but could be just a texture). What might I have to do differently to accomplish that? Are the steps in the tutorial conductive to this?
2. I would also like to render characters (either sprites or 3d models) on top of the tiles, such that they would look like they were not isometric at all (flat on the screen) in the center of the tile. How could I achieve this?

Comment: Hi I am also trying to do something like this. For the first one this link helped me a lot http://sertaogames.com/2013/01/30/isometric-tilesets-from-3d-modeling/. You might need to look into this. As for the second one I am looking for a solution where you able to figure out anything?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this by looking for the same and I can share what I have learned since there really is not much information about this.

First of all rendering objects and characters isometrically is the best way to go. Since you probably need 8 or even 16 dimensions a character can walk in. So if your walk cycle consists of only 4 frames you have a couple of weeks drawing to do. Quadruple that if you want the isometric map to rotate and have a fixed position for the sun. There really is not much about this, you do not even got to have the camera perfect for this.

For tiles that need to lineup with each other perfectly it's a whole different story. I have tried this in 3Ds max many times and it is very tedious to get that perfect 2:1 effect. This is because of the pixel grid, your 3D object will be translated into pixels and snap to that grid. So you might have a wall thats 64 units high that has an awkward 2:1 look. You can adjust that wall by .1 increments to correct the 2:1 look. But you have to do this for each straight line in that wall.

There does not seem to be a way to use any kind of anti aliasing to correct for this. If you would overlap an anti aliased image it will turn darker on the edges (or lighter if rendered against a bright background). This is obviously because of the anti aliased pixels are transparent and mix with the sprite behind it. One solution I am looking for is to create a blending mode that negates or removes this effect. But in the time I have been trying to get all this right I could have had all my walls drawn by hand.

There are plenty of sources that give you the camera and render setup. The camera needs to be angled 60 degrees for the 2:1 effect. In 3Ds Max you need to activate safe frames on your view-port and use the camera controls to place the object where you need to render. There is no need to worry about white space since plenty of texture packers remove this automatically.